Convert mp4 to webm using dash/ffmpeg technology
ffmpeg -i /2160.mp4 -deadline best -speed 1 \
          -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ar 48000 \
          -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
          -map v:0 -vf:v:0 "scale=-2:720,setsar=1:1,fps=60" -g 240 -minrate:v:0 900k -b:v:0 1800k -maxrate:v:0 2610k \
          -map 0:a \
          -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
          -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
          -dash_segment_type webm \
          -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 10 \
          -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
          -f dash/x6/dash.mpd

I'm facing a constant error
[dash @ 0x5592972d3040] Segment durations differ too much, enable use_timeline and use_template, or keep a stricter keyframe interval

There is a table of bitrates for each quality, which I adhere to
https://developers.google.com/media/vp9/settings/vod?hl=ru
It converts well, but nothing is said about dash, where can I read about it?
-g 240 -minrate:v:0 900k -b:v:0 1800k -maxrate:v:0 2610k

I can assume the problem is in these parameters...
All I can do is set the value at random and hope for success, which is fundamentally wrong...
Does anyone have any ideas to solve the problem?
Without the -g 240 parameter, the conversion completely failed in an arbitrary place...

The issue is a result of the combination of -g 240 and -seg_duration 10 (at 60fps).
Keeping a stricter keyframe interval:

-g 240 applies keyframe every 240 frames.
At 60 frames per second, the encoder add a keyframe every 4 seconds (240/60).
-seg_duration 10 sets the segment time to 10 seconds.

When splitting a video stream, the recommended (and default) is splitting at a keyframe.
There is a keyframe every 4 seconds, at times: at 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24...
When FFmpeg requires to split at 10sec, it can't, because it's not a keyframe.
The closest splitting times are at 8 seconds or at 12 seconds (instead of 10).
I am not sure about the splitting algorithm, but assume the first split is at 12 seconds, and the second split is at 20 seconds.
The result is 12 seconds long and 8 seconds long segments, which exceeds the recommended 50% recommended tolerance, so FFmpeg displays a warning message (not sure about FFmpeg warnings logic).
For more even splitting, set the GOP size to a multiple of segment duration, or vice versa (set the segment duration to a multiple of GOP size).
Examples:

For 10 seconds duration: set -g 120 (every 2 seconds) or -g 300 (every 5 seconds)...
For GOP size 240, set -seg_duration 8...


Example (selecting -seg_duration 8):
ffmpeg -i 2160.mp4 -deadline best -speed 1 \
          -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ar 48000 \
          -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
          -map v:0 -vf:v:0 "scale=-2:720,setsar=1:1,fps=60" -g 240 -minrate:v:0 900k -b:v:0 1800k -maxrate:v:0 2610k \
          -map 0:a \
          -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
          -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
          -dash_segment_type webm \
          -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 8 \
          -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
          -f dash dash.mpd


The warning message also says "enable use_timeline and use_template...".
When setting -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1, there is no warning.

The code shows an example with a video stream at 60 fps, there are also streams with 30 and 120 fps. I don't quite understand, if you specify a segment, for example, as 10 seconds, you need the -g parameter. Specify for each specific video stream? Since the segment can only be specified once...

-g can be set  with different value for each video stream. It is also possible to set -g 60. I think that -g 60 is OK for most cases. In case you like large GOP sizes like 240, you have to adjust the size to match the segment duration. You are correct that adjusting -g  according to the framerate and the segment duration is not ideal. When using FFmpeg from command line, there are no many choices (when using the C interface for example, we can insert a key frame were we want, but the C interface is much much more difficult). You can also check what is the purpose of -use_timeline 1

I wanted to ask, maybe you know, can you help me with this issue?
https://superuser.com/questions/1853510/error-starting-encoding-multiple-video-streams-ffmpeg
Thank you
