Error starting encoding, multiple video streams/FFMPEG
ffmpeg -i /2160.mp4 \
          -c:a libopus -b:a 128k -ar 48000 \
          -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 240 \
          -map v:0 -vf:v:0 "scale=-2:144"  \
          -map v:1 -vf:v:1 "scale=-2:240"  \
          -map 0:a \
          -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$" \
          -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$" \
          -dash_segment_type webm \
          -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 10 \
          -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
          -f dash /x6/dash.mpd

  Stream map 'v:1' matches no streams.
  To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.
  Failed to set value 'v:1' for option 'map': Invalid argument
  Error parsing options for output file /x6/dash.mpd.
  Error opening output files: Invalid argument

What kind of error is this, how to fix it?
I can assume that it is related to the audio stream. Is it necessary for each video stream, its own audio stream? Is it possible to make one audio track and play it on all video streams?

-map v:1 applies mapping the second video stream of the input file (at least when there is only one input file). I guess that 2160.mp4 has only one video stream, so there is an error. Try to ask what you like to archive, instead of just asking what is the reason for the error. I am sure you can find an example for MPD with two resolutions.

I don't understand that I'm doing something completely wrong...
I'm trying to make several streams from the original single file that I will play via https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/index.html
I don't remember exactly, but with the codec -c:v libx264, as far as I remember, I did exactly this before and it worked. Unfortunately, the example is not saved, how to do this with the codec -c:v libvpx-vp9

Am I doing something completely wrong? One input file, convert to 2 video streams with different extensions, bitrates. Compile on output in dash...

Not completely wrong... try to follow the example (or look for a better example). I recommend you to try asking a better question, after doing some research (Google searching). I think that -filter:v:1 is working but -vf:v:1 is not working. Start with -map 0:v:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:0.

Very good, thanks you
